# MySql Table with different colors by value

Tags: php, css, mysqli, colors, html-table

I am using mysql queries to fetch data from db. All my data are showing fine in tables. Now I want to color the status by value less than 2 or more than 3. 
The below code is not working.
Need help.

```
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
   $output .= '<div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table bordered">
         <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>genre</th>
            <th>time</th>
            <th>status</th>
            <th>more...</th>
         </tr>';
?>
<?php
   function status_style($row) {
      if ($row < 2) return 'background-color: #ff0000'; //red
      if ($row > 3) return 'background-color: #33cc33'; //green
      return '';
   }
?>
<?php
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
   {
      $output .= '
         <tr>
            <td>'.$row["name"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["genre"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["time"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["status"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["more"].'</td>
         </tr>
      ';
   }
   echo $output;
   {
      echo 'Data Not Found';
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already created function to color the rows but haven't called the function during showing output. That's why it is not working.

Change your `$output` variable with:

```
$output .= '
    <tr>
        <td>'.$row["name"].'</td>
        <td>'.$row["genre"].'</td>
        <td>'.$row["time"].'</td>
        <td style="'.status_style($row["status"]).'">'.$row["status"].'</td>
        <td>'.$row["more"].'</td>
     </tr>
';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
   $output .= '<div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table bordered">
         <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>genre</th>
            <th>time</th>
            <th>status</th>
            <th>more...</th>
         </tr>';
   function status_style($row) {
      if ($row < 2) return $color = '#ff0000'; //red
      if ($row > 3) return $color = '#33cc33'; //green
      return $color = '';
   }
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
   {
      $output .= '
         <tr style='"'background-color: '"' . $color . '"'>
            <td>'.$row["name"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["genre"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["time"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["status"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["more"].'</td>
         </tr>
      ';
   }
   echo $output;
   {
      echo 'Data Not Found';
   }
```

You didn't do anything with the background color.